# My github action keeps failing and I have no idea why

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, github-pages, npm-build

I wrote a github action to build and deploy my app and it fails with no definitive error.

[Here is an SS of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOqon.png).

[Here is an SS of the main.yml in my workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLIkr.png)

Comment: Please add entire action log and add code as text

Comment: Is your build passing on local ? Exit code 1 says otherwise.

Comment: You are trying to build the app, and it seems that have an unused variable named `FileBase`. Get rid of that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what was wrong, I had a build config switched on that was treating warnings as errors, the build process kept failing because of warnings. The solution was to switch it off like so;

change

```
"build": "react-scripts build"
```

to

```
"build": "CI=false react-scripts build"
```

in my package json.

By default the build process during the build process reads

```
"build": "CI=true react-scripts build"
```